# Adding data to database from custom form

Tags: magento2, database, forms, insertlisting, get

I'm able to fetch data from custom form but not able to put it in database table. Here I post details of model and controller

**SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\Name.php**

```
class Name extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Name');   
}
```

**SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Name.php**

```
 class Nameextends\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
  {
    public function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init("new_info","entity_id");
      }
   }
```

**SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Name\Collection.php**

```
  class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
  {
      public function _construct()
      {
       $this->_init("SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\Name","SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Name");
      }
  }
```

**Controller\Test.php**

```
$model = $this->_name->create();
$entity = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$model->addData([
    "entity_id" => $entity['entity_id'],
    "customer_id" => $entity['customer_id'],
    "position" => $entity['position'],
    "department" => $entity['department']
]);

$saveData = $model->save();

if($saveData)
{
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Record Inserted...!');
}
else
{
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Record Inserted...!');
 }
```

Table Structure -

```
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
 {
     public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, 
     ModuleContextInterface $context)
     {
       $setup->startSetup();

        $name = $setup->getTable('new_info');
    // Create your table now
    $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($name
    )->addColumn(
        'entity_id',
        Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        [
            'identity' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'primary' => true
        ],
        'ID'
    )->addColumn(
        'customer_id',
        Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        255,
        [
            'nullable' => false
        ],
        'Customer ID'
    )->addColumn(
        'position',
        Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        [
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => ''
        ],
        'Position of employee'
    )->addColumn(
        'department',
        Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        [
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => ''
        ],
        'Department of employee'
)->setComment("Custom_table");
$setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$setup->endSetup();
```

}

Comment: can you please provide us more details, like which error is displaying?

Comment: **No Errors** but not even adding to database table

Comment: so I think it is printing data not inserted which will be in else part, right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe its issue in your $saveData, you can var_dump that,

try this:

```
$model = $this->_name->create();
$entity = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
$model->addData([
    "entity_id" => $entity['entity_id'],
    "customer_id" => $entity['customer_id'],
    "position" => $entity['position'],
    "department" => $entity['department']
]);
try{
      $model->save();
      $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Saved Successfully'));
   }
catch(\Exception $e){
      $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

**Controller\Test.php**

```
<?php
$model = $this->_name->create();
$entity = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

$model->setData([
    "entity_id" => $entity['entity_id'],
    "customer_id" => $entity['customer_id'],
    "position" => $entity['position'],
    "department" => $entity['department']
]);

// Or you can used this if above code not worked.
// $model->setEntityId($entity['entity_id']);
// $model->setCustomerId($entity['customer_id']);
// $model->setPosition($entity['position']);
// $model->setDepartment($entity['department']);

$saveData = $model->save();

if($saveData)
{
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Record Inserted...!');
}
else
{
    $this->messageManager->addError('Something went wrong..!!');
}
```

Comment: Not working... I am getting Record Inserted but values ain't adding.

Comment: have you try both way ?

Comment: please add database table structure in question

Comment: yes Itried both

Comment: insert data manually in table and try to print data using controller

Comment: Yes. Its printing...

Comment: try to print this $model->getData() aftert set data, try to debug more